# How to make a partial record with io-ts?

Tags: typescript

How does one make a partial record in `io-ts`?

I want to achieve something similar using `io-ts` and `t.partial` does not appear to accept `t.record` as a prop.

```js
type Pets = keyof { dog: undefined; cat: undefined; fish: undefined };
interface PetCounts extends Partial<Record<Pets, number>> {}
```